# DropDown list doesnt update selected value

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a `dropdownlist`:

```
<div class="a">
    @Html.DropDownList("StorageId", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StorageId)
</div>
```

Html:

```
<div class="a">
                <select class="form-control" id="StorageId" name="StorageId"><option selected="selected" value="1">Brak Brak</option>
<option value="2">First</option>
<option value="23">Second</option>
<option value="24">Third</option>
</select>
                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="StorageId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
```

populated with code:

```
ViewBag.StorageId = new SelectList(unitOfWork.storageRepository.Get(), "Id", "Name", deviceusage.StorageId);
```

all data is send to controller with this Ajax request:

```
    $.ajax({
    url: "/DeviceUsage/Edit",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    headers: {
        'RequestVerificationToken': '@TokenHeaderValue()'
    },
    data: JSON.stringify({
        deviceusage: {
            DeviceInstanceId: $('.a').children("#DeviceInstanceId").val(),
            UserId: $('.a').children('#UserId').val(),
            StorageId: $('.a').children('#storageId').val()

        }
    }),
    error: function (data) {
        alert("wystąpił nieokreślony błąd " + data);
    },
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.ok) {
            $("#Modal").modal('hide');
            window.location = data.newurl;
        }
        else {
            $('.modal-body').html(data);
       }
    }
})
```

No Matter what I select in this dropdown it's not updated. After changing first selection always first one is send to controller.

@Update:
Here is a controller method I use for handling 'Post` calls:

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include="StorageId,UserId,DeviceInstanceId")] DeviceUsage deviceusage)
    {
        ValidateRequestHeader(Request);
        if (deviceusage.UserId == 6 && deviceusage.StorageId == (int)Storage.Biurko)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Zarezerwowane urządzenie nie moze byc przypisane do biurka");
        }
        if (deviceusage.UserId == 1 && deviceusage.StorageId == (int)Storage.Biurko)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Wolne urządzenie nie może przebywać na jakimś biurku");
        }
        if ((deviceusage.UserId != 1 & deviceusage.UserId != 6) & deviceusage.StorageId != (int)Storage.Biurko)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Urzązenie przypisane do kogos nie moze przebywac w magazynie");
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            unitOfWork.deviceUsageRepository.Update(deviceusage);
            unitOfWork.Save();
            return Json(new { ok = true, newurl = Url.Action("Index") });
        }
        ViewBag.DeviceInstanceId = new SelectList(unitOfWork.deviceInstanceRepository.Get(), "Id", "SerialNo", deviceusage.DeviceInstanceId);
        ViewBag.StorageId = new SelectList(unitOfWork.storageRepository.Get(), "Id", "Name", deviceusage.StorageId);
        var data = unitOfWork.userRepository.Get()
        .Select(s => new
        {
            Id = s.Id,
            Credentials = s.Name + " " + s.Surname
        }
        );
        ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(data, "Id", "Credentials", deviceusage.UserId);
        return PartialView(deviceusage);
    }
```

As you can see its returning a `PartialView` because dropdown is in modal windows which is updated with a return of `Ajax` call.

@Update2

During test using browser console with this code:

```
$('#StorageId').val()
```

I managed to find that:

- its correctly returning values before **first send**
- if the modal is reloaded because of that the data was wrong. Changing selected value using  list does not change anything. The value returned with this code is falue send with ajax.

Comment: Could you post the html dom structure of the generated Dropdown list box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind the  issue that always first value is getting submitted to controller is because of this attr which is set to first option in your dropdown list box,`selected="selected"`.

You could bypass this behaviour with change event call back like this

**JQUERY CODE:**

```
$('.a select').on('change',function() {
      $(this).find('option:selected').attr("selected","selected");
});
```

Add the above event listener inside the `$(document).ready( function() { ...... })` or `onload` of the body of your page.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Sorry still nothing. I Updated question with additional data

Comment: @szpic: could you alert the `$('.a').children('#StorageId').val();` with in your  `data` block of `ajax` call

Comment: At this moment effect are like this: Modal appears. I choose some value from list and send it. Alert show eq `23` and for some reason its wrong value ( checking in controller). Modal windows is updated with new html. I'm changing selected item in the dropdown for eq `1` and this alert shows `23` instead of `1`

Comment: try `$('.a #StorageId').val();` and alert this value to verify its the correct selection what u made

Comment: @well its clear that, when your modal data is re-loaded, the dropdown list is corrupting. it would be worth checking the `data` returned from ajax call whether the html is constructed properly.

Comment: Thanks for help. It appeared that there was second modal in the code uncommented. And this was causing mess in the code!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
StorageId: $('.a').children('#StorageId').val()
```

note uppercase 'S' on `#StorageId`

Also you could probably just do:

```
StorageId: $('#StorageId :selected').val();
```

I've created a jsfiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/2qpBZ/

Comment: Sorry this doesn't change anything